# Is there an algorithm for filling a 2D matrix with data based only a small number of starting values?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, 2d

I have a 2D grid, and an array of points within the grid. (To make it easier to discuss, let's think of them as colours in a bitmap.)

I have a certain number of *real pixels* where I know the colour, the rest of the bitmap is blank.

[Here's an example with 5 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmdvX.jpg)

For any given pixel in the bitmap, I want to colour it based on its proximity to the real pixels (where I do know the colour).

[This is roughly what it should look like when complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzBcg.jpg)

I'm finding it hard to figure out the areas that each real pixel should be able to influence. Here are some cases:

[Case (A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKrdi.jpg) - feels like it wants to use the 4 colours around it. Gut feel is that 4 is probably the most colours it needs to use? Perhaps I could find the nearest real pixel in each quadrant around the pixel?

[Case (B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAZbA.jpg) - feels like it can only use 3 colours, because it's near an edge. It doesn't want yellow. Blue and red are both in the bottom left quadrant, so I can't just get the closest real pixel. Blue is closer than green, it seems right to use it. Maybe both blue and red are relevant because they are a certain number of degrees angle apart?

[Case (C)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ676.jpg) - this one feels like green is irrelevant. Magenta is very close, and on a similar angle.

Before I just start coding, I wanted to find out if there is already a good algorithm to do this kind of thing. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks for your time...

Comment: Look up scattered data interpolation. There are a lot of approaches (e.g. radial basis functions, Shepard interpolation, natural neighbor interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nico for the response. I have a working solution, although I don't know if it's the best thing possible. But if anyone comes across this, here's what I did.

(The arrays might be unique to the framework I'm using but you ge the general idea.)

[Here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEAHd.jpg)

It doesn't set any boundaries for how far the colour influences, but I can get a good result by reducing the influence of the colour as it moves away from the source point.

```
//c++

void buildMatrix(){

    matrix.clear();

    // for each pixel
    for (int x = 0; x < 128; ++x){
        for (int y = 0; y < 128; ++y){

            auto matrix_point = new MatrixPoint(x,y);

            // for each point where I know the colour, find out how far it is from this point
            for (int colour_index = 0; colour_index < colours.size(); ++colour_index)
            {
                int x2 = colours[colour_index].x;
                int y2 = colours[colour_index].y;

                auto distance = getColourAmount(x, y,x2,y2);

                matrix_point->distance_index.add(colour_index, distance});

                if (x == x2 && y == y2)
                {
                    // found a solid colour, no need to add any more colours to this point
                    break;
                }
            }

            // scale the results so they add up to 1
            float total_percentage = 0.0f;

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix_point->distance_index.size(); ++i)
            {
                float this_percentage = matrix_point->distance_index[i].percent;
                total_percentage += this_percentage;
            }

            // scale percentages so that they add up to 1
            for (auto &item : matrix_point->distance_index)
            {
                item.setY(item.getY() / total_percentage);
            }

            matrix.add(*matrix_point);
        }
    }
}

float getColourAmount(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    float deltaX = x1 - x2;
    float deltaY = y1 - y2;
    float max_distance = sqrtf(128 * 128 + 128 * 128);
    auto output = (max_distance - sqrtf((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY))) / max_distance;
    return pow(output,10); // scale down the result 
}
```